# svn patch edited files

Tags: svn, diff, patch

Is it possible to patch a file that has been edited? right now I get the following error:

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file

I know that hunk 1 has code that needs to be patched over.

Answer (score 1):

You manually edit to apply the rejected hunks.

Comment: So I just need to manually edit the diff file and remove things that will conflict? I can do that but in a way, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having a diff document?

Comment: After you run patch ,the possible patches are 'applied' and the impossible patches are rejected. All you can do then is apply the impossible ones by using your brain and a text editor. Patch files aren't that useful when other people have been changing the code.